# If $\pi \in (0,1)$ then prove that $f(x) = \pi g_1(x) + (1 - \pi) g_2(x)$ is a density function.

Tags: probability, random-variables

Let $g_1(x)$ and $g_2(x)$ be two density functions in $R$. 
$ \ $  If $\pi \in (0,1)$ then prove that 
$f(x) = \pi g_1(x) + (1 - \pi) g_2(x)$ is a density function.

Well by definition I know that is a density function if for any $a, b \in R \ $

$P(x \in [a,b]) = \int_{a}^{b} f(x) dx$

$=\pi\int_{a}^{b} g_1(x)dx + (1 - \pi)\int_{a}^{b} g_2(x)dx$

which is well defined because both of $g_1$ and $g_2$ are density functions.

I don´t know how to proced next because (I know that I haven´t use my hipotesis yet)

Answer (score 1):

Guide:

- Check that $f$ integrates to $1$ when you integrate from $-\infty$ to $\infty$.
- Check that $f$ is nonnegative.

If these conditions are satisfied, then we have a pdf.